# Remove the columns having 40-50% values as NULL in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in which there are many columns having 40-50% of values null.

I want to remove those columns from my dataframe. I have got the percentage of empty rows using the following code:

```
(colMeans(is.na(application_data))*100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `colSums()` and `!` operator to filter columns more than your threshold:

```
application_data_40<-application_data[,!colSums(is.na(application_data)) >= 40 ]
application_data_50<-application_data[,!colSums(is.na(application_data)) >= 50 ]
```